# In Python, how can I send a Queue to a multiprocessing.Process after it has already been started?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

Typically I do something like:

```
q = Queue()
p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
p.start()
```

Is there some way to pass p another Queue?  Er... now that I think about it - can this be done through q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it can be done via `q`. You can pass any object there, another `Queue` included
2. I wouldn't recommend this practice, however. Describe why you originally need this, maybe there's a better design.

Comment: Is a queue of queues any more outre than a list of lists or dict of dicts?

Comment: @Paul: IMHO yes, because Queue is a synchronized communication mechanism, not a simple data structure. That Python allows to create queues of queues doesn't mean they're a good idea

Answer (score 1):

No, once a process has been created (the process is forked), queues can no longer be sent to it. They can only be sent at process creation time. To do otherwise results in an exception.